# JSF + rich:fileupload + param

Tags: jsf, null, richfaces, param

I am using `<rich:fileupload>` and I need to send some extra parameters to my Controller. I tried to use `<f:param>` for this.

Here is the view:

```
<rich:fileUpload 
    fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.listener}"
    maxFilesQuantity="#{fileUploadController.uploadsAvailable}"
    addControlLabel="Hinzufügen"
    uploadControlLabel="Hochladen"
    cancelEntryControlLabel="Abbrechen"
    doneLabel="Fertig"
    clearAllControlLabel="Alle entfernen"
    noDuplicate="true"
    stopControlLabel="Stop"
    clearControlLabel="Entfernen"
    id="upload"                             
    immediateUpload="#{fileUploadController.autoUpload}"  
    ajaxSingle="true"
    acceptedTypes="jpg" 
    allowFlash="#{fileUploadController.useFlash}"
    rerender="info">

    <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="info" status="globalStatus" />

    <f:param 
    value="#{imageFormat}"  
    name="#{fileUploadController.imageFormat}"/>

</rich:fileUpload>
```

Here is the `FileUploadController` backing bean:

```
    private String imageFormat;

    public void setImageFormat(String imageFormat) {
        this.imageFormat = imageFormat;
    }

    public String getImageFormat() {
        return imageFormat;
    }
```

However, the setter is never called, so the variable is always `null`. The `#{imageFormat}` has the correct value, I verified it with an `<h:outputText>`.

I can't use `<a4j:param>`, because there is no button to hook on.

We are using JSF 1.2, not JSF 2.0.

Comment: I didn't get your point but if you want to know the image format the whole image you have in your listener method you can easily identify what is the format.

Comment: No, i have an STRING which is in #{imageFormat} (the Format it should be)

i just wanna know, how get the param from my rich:fileupload to my Controller

Comment: If such approach with f:param will ever work, it should be: <f:param value="#{fileUploadController.imageFormat}" name="imageFormat"/>

Comment: @Andrey:

but the value in #{fileUploadController.imageFormat} is null

i want to fill it via a param ....  

is there any possibility to do it?
something like: 
`<a4j:param name="imageFormat" value="#{imageFormat} binding="#{fileUploadController.imageFormat}" />`

but this is not working here. would be perfect.

Comment: @Joerg I have specified more events supported by rich:fileUpload. If it is not what are you looking for, please provide more details, what is that imageFormat variable, where it is come from, and what is it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform some operations on specific phases of upload, you can attach to an event of rich:fileUpload. Along with standard events, rich:fileUpload provides a number of specific events:

- The "onadd" event handler called on an add file operation
- The "onupload" which gives you a possibility to cancel the upload at
  client side
- The "onuploadcomplete" which is called after all files from the list
  are uploaded
- The "onuploadcanceled" which is called after upload has been canceled
  via cancel control
- The "onerror" which is called if the file upload was interrupted
  according to any errors

To invoke server side logic using AJAX when event occurs, use 'a4j:status' or 'a4j:jsFunction', for example using 'a4j:status':

```
<rich:fileUpload
        yourParameters="...">
    <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="something" action="#{fileUploadController.setImageFormat(imageFormat)}"/>
</rich:fileUpload>
```

and using 'a4j:jsFunction' (also demonstrated how to use setPropertyActionListener, it is for case if your EL resolver does not support method invocations with parameters (refer to BalusC comment))

```
<rich:fileUpload onupload="setImageFormat();"
        yourParameters="..."></rich:fileUpload>

<a4j:jsFunction name="setImageFormat">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{imageFormat}" target="#{fileUploadController.imageFormat}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

Comment: Invoking non-getter methods with arguments in EL is not supported prior EL 2.2. And since OP is using JSF 1.2, I doubt that he is running an EL 2.2 capable container (EL 2.2 is part of Java EE 6 which in turn offers JSF 2.0).

Comment: @BalusC Regarding methods with parameters invocation. I did not want to overload the answer with that details, just wanted to demonstrate the approach. It might work as is for Joerg, if he is using, for example, JBoss EL. If not in this particular case f:setPropertyActionListener is appropriate.